# Cómo eliminar filas repetidas de un DF siempre y cuando se cumplan varias condiciones - R

Tags: r, condiciones, rstudio, filtro, eliminar

Escribo porque no he podido saber cómo realizar un proceso en R, he leído varios documentos, pero no encuentro algo que me pueda servir. Espero puedan ayudarme

Lo que debo hacer es lo siguiente, imaginen que tengo una tabla como la que les adjunto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**SI** la variable “CODIGO” tiene registros repetidos Y TAMBIEN **SI** la variable “FECHA DE CAPTURA” tiene esos mismos registros repetidos, **ENTONCES** por favor elimina o filtra la fila cuyo valor en la variable “PRECIO” sea menor.

Noten que en la tabla que les adjunto las filas 1 y 2 cumplen con las 2 condiciones, en este caso debería quitarse o filtrarse toda la fila 2, debido a que su precio es de 24.000, que es menor al de 25.000 de la fila 1.

Puede haber casos en donde existan registros repetidos en la variable CODIGO, pero esos mismos registros NO estén repetidos para la variable FECHA DE CAPTURA, y viceversa,  en ese tipo de casos no se debe hacer nada, hay que darlo todo tal como está, mirar la tabla que les adjunto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven en la segunda tabla, las 3 primeras filas tienen registros repetidos en la variable CODIGO, pero esos mismos registros NO están repetidos para la variable FECHA DE CAPTURA, en ese caso no debe hacerse nada.

No he podido hallar la manera de realizar esto en R, entiendo que debería ser con un IF o un IFELSE, pero no he dado con la forma. Espero puedan ayudarme. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te adjunto una solución utilizando la libreria tidyverse

Creamos una variable auxiliar, como la concatenación del código y la fecha,
luego ordenamos la base de datos por la variable auxiliar y el precio de menor a mayor con la función arrange, finalmente eliminamos duplicados usando la función distinct con el parámetro keep_all = T para mantener las variables.

```
   df %>% mutate(aux = paste(code, fecha)) %>% # crear variable auxiliar
     arrange(aux, desc(precio)) %>% # ordenar bbdd
     distinct(aux, .keep_all = T) %>% # eliminar duplicados
     select(-aux) # eliminar variable auxiliar
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda! Te quería preguntar que ya que lo que busco es que cuando el script detecte que hay alguna repetición (de 2 o más observaciones) en la variable Código, se dirija a la variable Date para chequear si también tiene repeticiones en esas mismas filas, y si los tiene elimine la o las filas en donde el valor en Precio sea menor. Teniendo en cuenta ello, el script que enviaste cumple con ello? disculpa es que soy un poco nuevo en este lenguaje.

Comment: si, eso hace, prueba con una base de datos similar a la que mostraste

Comment: Mil gracias amigo!! De verdad gracias por tu ayuda, me funcionó super bien (Y)

Comment: Una ultima cosa, disculpa. Como en mi base de datos tengo múltiples NA y ceros, cuando corro el código que me indicaste se pierden muchas filas dado que R toma esos registros como repetidos, en sentido cómo hago para  que el código no tome en cuenta los NA y los ceros?